# Get the last inserted row ID (HFSQL)

Tags: windev

I need to get the Id(Auto Incremented) created for an inserted Row

How i can do that the documentation mentioned `LAST_INSERT_ID` but i don't know how to use it ,
i tried this but it does not work :

```
Insert into tab1 (tab1.Name) values('foo')
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID ()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this :

```
Insert into tab1 (tab1.Name) values('foo')
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID() FROM tab1 LIMIT 1
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

You can use:

```
SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('tablename')
```

to access the latest identity for a particular table.

For Example:

```
 INSERT INTO YourTable(columns....) VALUES(..........)
 SELECT IDENT_CURRENT('YourTable')
```